# C++ header include conflict

Tags: c++, header, include

I am working on a traffic simulation program for school. My `Simulation` class reads in a list of vehicles from an XML file, so I have included `Vehicle.h` in my `Simulation` class. I want my vehicle to be able to hold a pointer to the simulation object so that it can use the simulation's `searchRoads` function. So I included `Simulation.h` in my `Vehicle` class.

When I did this, I got over 100 errors when I tried to compile. I'm pretty iffy on my C++ so if I committed some sort of cardinal sin, please let me know how to rectify this.

Comment: 1) include guards. 2) post your code. 3) not **all** your code, of course, just an example that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either, You are missing inclusion guards, leading to multiple inclusion of header files

Or

You are creating a **[Circular Dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency#Example_of_circular_dependencies_in_C.2B.2B)** of your headers. You should be rather using **[Forward Declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)**.

Post details of your code for more detailed answer.

Comment: I made a circular dependency. I figured it was something like that, I just didn't know what it was called. I had no idea it was as simple to fix as it was. Thank you for the links also! Code is working! :D

Comment: @X_X: Glad could I help, Do post minimalistic code sample of your problem from hereon to get quick answers and oh do accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Will do, now I need to go through all my files and get rid of these stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You learn something about include guards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard
Hope this helps.

Comment: good, that's usually the best practice for start!glad to see that the answer from Als helped. mine was more a shot in the dark

Answer (score 0):

Since operating systems have the ability to handle long file names I've started naming my include files so they reflect the code's position in the namespace:

```
namespace network {
 class connection { bool send( char* stuff ); }
}
```

Would end up in the file "network.connection.h".

It helps keep things organized and reduces the chance of name collision of files.